# ARDUINO - button

Tags: button, colors, arduino, sensors, arduino-uno

I have a program with arduino UNO and a color sensor, witch shows me RGB values.
I have a button, too, witch may start the reading of an object (colored papper), but when I press it, the program reads for 5 times, not for once, like I want.
In every case(for every color), I want to add a value to a variable witch I want to show in Serial monitor, but after a reading (or 5 readings:))), the serial monitor shows only the value that I want to add to my variable (eg. c=c+2; serial motior: 2 for every press of the button).

Here is my code:

```
// Define pins
const int ledpin = 13;
const int GSR1 = 12;
const int GSR0 = 11;
const int GSG1 = 10;
const int GSG0 = 9;
const int GSB1 = 8;
const int GSB0 = 7;

int redpin = A0;
int greenpin = A1;
int bluepin = A2;


const int buttonPin = 6;

// Sensor read values
int red = 0;
int green = 0;
int blue = 0;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

  pinMode(ledpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GSR1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GSR0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GSG1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GSG0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GSB1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GSB0, OUTPUT);

  // Turn on the LED
  digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);

  // Set the gain of each sensor
  digitalWrite(GSR1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GSR0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GSG1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GSG0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GSB1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(GSB0, LOW);
}

void loop()  
{  
   int buttonState;


   buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);



   //  Read sensors

   red = analogRead(redpin) * 10;
   green = analogRead(greenpin) * 14;
   blue = analogRead(bluepin) * 17;
   int c=0;
   int br=0;


   if (buttonState == HIGH) 
   {
    if (1200>red && red>1000 && 1950>green && green>1500 && 850>blue && blue>650)
    {
      Serial.print("yellow");
      Serial.print("\n");
      c=2;
    }

    if(c==2)
    {
      br=br+2;
      Serial.print(br);
      Serial.print("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you debounce the button.

Comment: In your code, you have `int br=0;` *inside* the `loop()` function. Hence, `br` is reset to 0 in every iteration. Declare `br` outside of a function and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be able to help you to imagine what's happening. The first time the loop executes and the button is pressed, buttonState is set to HIGH. Because the loop is faster than your buttonPress, it executes multiple times while you have the button depressed. Sounds like what you really want is for the code that prints data to execute once for each button press. To accomplish this, you need to track the change state of the button. You can do this with an additional variable.

For example:

```
//Define tracker as a variable at the top of the sketch.
int tracker = 0;
```

Then in loop, only execute when tracker and buttonState are different:

```
buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
if (tracker != buttonState)
{
    if (buttonState == HIGH){
        // put all of your print code here
    }

    //then set tracker equal to buttonState
    tracker = buttonState;
}
```

The logic is:

-tracker and buttonState begin as 0 (LOW).
-When the button is pressed, buttonState = HIGH and tracker = LOW.
  buttonState and tracker are not equal so the code enters the first if clause.
  buttonState is HIGH, so the code enters the second if clause (prints data)
  tracker is then set to buttonState, i.e. HIGH

-when the loop comes around again:
if the button is still pressed, buttonState and tracker are still equal so the code doesn't enter the first clause. Therefore, nothing gets printed.
if the button is no longer pressed, then buttonState is LOW and tracker is HIGH. The first if clause is entered. buttonState is LOW so the print section will not execute. tracker is set to buttonState, so they are now both LOW. Back to where we started.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

a)  Do you have a pulldown resistor on pin 6?

b) the fact that you only see the number 2 in the result is due to the fact that you reset the variable br every time the function loop() is called. If you make br static it will only be initialised once, which is what you want.

c) You should check for a LOW to HIGH transition in the value returned by digitalRead(buttonPin) instead of just checking for a HIGH value. The way your code is now, if you hold the button long enough, loop will run any times and every time it will see that digitalRead(buttonPin) returns HIGH - this explains your '5 times' problem. If after changing this you still see many presses instead of one, then your problem will probably be debouncing - you can google the word for a thorough explanation and even sample code, but in short you should discard LOW to HIGH transitions that are too close together in time.

Answer (score 0):

Your button state is made wrong try this:

```
//Your declared pins

...


//Buttons

int button1 = 7;





//States for obj and Button (1)

int state1 = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading1;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous1 = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin




// the follow variables are long's because the time, measured in miliseconds,
// will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
long time1 = 0;          // the last time the output pin was toggled

long debounce1 = 200;   // the debounce time, increase if the output flickers


...


void loop() {

  reading1 = digitalRead(button1);


  // if the input just went from LOW and HIGH and we've waited long enough
  // to ignore any noise on the circuit, toggle the output pin and remember
  // the time
  //Condition 1
  if (reading1 == HIGH && previous1 == LOW && millis() - time1 > debounce1) {
    if (state1 == HIGH)
      state1 = LOW;
    else
      state1 = HIGH;

    time1 = millis();   
  }


//put as many variables as you want here connected to state1
//If you see relay somewhere or I forgot brackets please let me know
//I just adapted an old project with relays that was similar
if(state1 == HIGH){
     //YOUR STUFF

}

  digitalWrite(yourvariable, state1); //In case you want to turn on something

//you can find a way to nest this "if statements for the button" if you want
  previous1 = reading1;

}
```